# To print python's sys.path from the command line

Tags: python

I want to print python's sys.path from the command line, but this one is not working:

```
python -m sys  -c "print (sys.path)"
```

although `print -c "import sys; print (sys.path)"` would work. It seems that "-m" in the first one above does not load the module "sys". Any clarification on how to correctly import a module from python flags? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such flag. `-m` does something completely different from what you want. You can go through the [Python command line docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) to see the lack of such a flag if you want.

Just put the import in the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "import sys; print (sys.path)"
```